# Passing URL Parameter to PHP Variable

Tags: php, variables, get

I have the below code and im trying to use the parameter in the URL to get a match from my database. I keep getting my error message 'something failed'. The URL reads:

```
http://www.examplesite.com/template.php?eventname=3506
```

The code:

```
<?php
require_once("./source/include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;
}

// Make a MySQL Connection
...

// Retrieve the variable from the url
if(!empty($_GET['eventname'])) {
    $eventname = $_GET['eventname'];
} else {
    //set default value for $eventname or maybe output an error because eventname isn't set
    echo '<p>', 'something failed', '</p>';
}
```

Comment: have you looked at a var_dump($_GET)? It appears $_GET['eventname'] is empty.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Simple, you are not getting this from your form $_GET['eventname']. So check your form html to see that field name

Comment: Not sure why `$_GET['eventname']` wouldn't work in your case, but you could try `$_REQUEST['eventname']`.

Comment: hmmm, how can it be empty if there is a number in the url?

Comment: Yes, trying echoing out `$_GET['eventname']` before all else

Comment: Interesting, try print_r($_GET) for a second

Comment: Technically your question has nothing to do with Mysql. I removed that part so you can concentrate on the concrete problem.

Comment: Do the `var_dump($_GET); die();` and look inside the HTML source in your browser then what there actually is with `$_GET`. Like suggested in the very first comment 30 minutes ago. Add the output to the question.

Comment: I guess its empty, but I just dont see why.

Answer (score 0):

You code *should* work, unless something is interfering with the query string.

**First**

Replace this line:

```
echo '<p>', 'something failed', '</p>';
```

With:

```
printf("<pre>Something Failed:\n%s\n</pre>", var_export($_GET, true));
exit;
```

Which will include some *meaningful* data with the error message, then exit so you're not continuing with bad/missing data in the rest of your script. [[printf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) is a very handy function to learn as well]

**Second**

If the above does not reveal anything to you, then look for a `.htaccess` file in your site that might have a RewriteRule in place that's messing with the query string.

Comment: I got something failed: array()

Comment: and no rewrite rule in place in .htaccess

Comment: @user1949586 Try doing a `phpinfo()` and check the value of [`variables_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order). If there is not a `G` in it then `$_GET` will not be created.

Comment: @user1949586 bump the `var_export($_GET)` up to the very top of your page, and see if it exists there. If so, then something further down in your code/includes is messing with it. If it's *still* not there then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Yeah I bumped it up and same result. Uhhh so frustrating! Would it help for you to see how the URL is generated?

Answer (score 0):

Side note : don't let you database sabotaged by not escaping what you put in your query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_id = '$eventname'")
```

Use [mysql_real_esape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)($eventname) instead.

Comment: Or better yet, abandon deprecated `mysql_*` functions and start using PDO or mySQLi.